# Why this strange behaviour of 'round' built in.(python 2.6)

Tags: python, rounding

Why So ?

```
>>> round(2/3)
```

0.0

```
>>> round(0.66666666666666666666666666666667)
```

1.0

```
>>> round(2.0/3)
```

1.0

Answer (score 16, accepted):

That's not strange behaviour from `round()`:

Try this:

```
>>> 2/3
0
```

Using `/` with two integer values will do an integer division. So the *argument* to `round()` is *already* 0, which makes `round()` return 0.

**Update:** as @Mark noted in the comment, [this behaviour changed in Python 3](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/): `2/3` will do a floating point division as `2.0/3` does in Python 2. `2//3` can be used to get integer division behaviour on both versions).

Your last example works, because `2.0` is not integer, so `2.0/3` will do a "propper" floating point division:

```
>>> 2.0/3
0.6666666666666666
```

Comment: Note this is true for python 1.x and 2.x but python >- 3 has changed this so 2/3 gives 0.6666666666666666 see <http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0238/>